# Malloc to struct; segmentation fault

Tags: c, struct, malloc

So I defined my struct outside of any function:

```
typedef struct limb{
    char c;
    struct limb *child;
    int x;
    int y;
}limb;
```

And tried to allocate memory to it:

```
limb *body;
body = malloc(sizeof(limb));
body->child = malloc(sizeof(limb));
```

But it gives me segmentation fault. 
Any help will be appreciated.

gdb:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000409162 in wsyncdown ()
(gdb) x 0x0000000000409162
0x409162 <wsyncdown+18>:    0x406f8b48
```

Whole code (hope it helps):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

int max_x, max_y;

void welcome_screen();
void terrain();

typedef struct limb{
    char c;
    struct limb *child;
    int x;
    int y;
}limb;

int main()
{
    welcome_screen();
    terrain();
    return 0;
}
void terrain()
{
    WINDOW *terrain;
    int startx, starty, width, height;
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    wrefresh(terrain);
    height = 60;
    width = 100;
    starty = (LINES - height) / 2;
    startx = (COLS - width) / 2;
    terrain = newwin(height, width, starty, startx);
    wborder(terrain, '|', '|', '-', '-', '+', '+', '+', '+');
    wrefresh(terrain);
    limb *body;
    if(!(body = malloc(sizeof(limb)))){
        printw("SEGMENTATION FAULT");
        getch();
    }
    /*body->child = malloc(sizeof(limb));*/


    while(1);
    endwin();
}
```

Comment: The code looks fine. Are you sure it's here? Did you use a debugger?

Comment: Where does it crash?

Comment: What is the need of `struct limb *child;` here? and why you are allocating memory for that?

Comment: I am making a snake game and I want to make the body of the snake using structs with pointers to the next struct; I don't know any better way to do it.

Comment: It's programmer's responsibility to check if `malloc` hasn't returned null pointer. Dereferencing null pointer in undefined behaviour. In other words your code assumes that `body = malloc(sizeof(limb));` always succeeds, but this might not be the case (due to various reasons).

Comment: It is like a linked list?. If yes means no need to allocate memory for Structure pointer. I think allocating memory for that structure pointer causing the problem!

Comment: @Igor: The design idea isn't bad, it's a linked list. But you still haven't told us where it crashes. You need to inspect this with a debugger and investigate further, the code fragment you've posted can only crash if your system runs out of memory or if you try to reference `body->child->child` (since `body->child` is valid but initialized).

Comment: @Sathish I tried removing it, and it still gives seg fault.

Comment: @Igor with out your error and code it is difficult to solve your problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This causes undefined behaviour:

```
WINDOW *terrain;
// ...
wrefresh(terrain);
```

because you use an uninitialized variable. Take out the `wrefresh(terrain)` line. To avoid this sort of error you could delay declaring variables until you are ready to initialize them:

```
// ...
WINDOW *terrain = newwin(height, width, starty, startx);
```

Comment: Interesting, what do you think why it didn't cause a crash before I started to initialize the structure?

Comment: That would depend on what `wrefresh` does exactly, and what the random memory that `terrain` points to contained (amongst other things)

Comment: The crash message seems to indicate the error is in `wsyncdown` (presumably this function is called by `wrefresh`) and not anything to do with the malloc